# Javascript div dynamic value change with settimeout

Tags: javascript, dynamic, return-value

I am running a php script, which sends email to each users, there will be total more than 100 emails, hence I want to show a real time progressive output in my page, while script sends email to all users.

How can I display results like below with setTimeOut option:

```
Sending 1...
Sending 2...
Sending 3...
Sending 4...
Sending 5...
```

Its fine if I have to set like:

```
function mve() {

for (; i < 10; )
{
    document.getElementById('ttlcnt').innerHTML = i;
    i++;
}

}
var foo = setTimeout('mve()', 1000);
```

Above function doesn't update the div value on regular event, it just updates to `Sending 10...` only

Please help me achieve this type of counter using Javascript, so users feel it is real time update.

Thanks in advance !

Comment: you need to do `for (i=0; i < 10; )`

Comment: How is the javascript (above) reflecting what's truly going on at the server? You need to communicate with the php mail script to get callbacks after each send.

Comment: You should probably place your js code in the php loop that is sending the mails otherwise you will have no idea when a mail has been sent.

Comment: @karthikr what good will that do?

Comment: i need idea, how to achieve this, that's why I have ask question here, not to downvote man 1

Comment: for( ... ) setTimeout(); is the correct way, NOT a for inside the functions (it always evaluate until 10 per every timer)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
function mve(i) {
    document.getElementById('ttlcnt').innerHTML = i;
}

for(i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
    setTimeout("mve(i)", 1000*i); // This will call mve() every 1 second, for 10 seconds
}
```

If you need to store the reference to the timer, save it inside an array.

Answer (score 0):

You can try:

```
function mve(i){
    if(i < 10){
        var x = document.getElementById("ttlcnt");
        x.innerHTML = "sending " + i + "...";
    }
}

var i = 1;

setInterval('abc(i); i++;',1000);
```